# Easy Angular way to detect if element is in viewport on scroll

Tags: angular, angularjs, scroll, angular-directive

I'm trying to find an easy solution for my Angular App to check if an element is visible on scrolling and if it is then fire some animations.
So, normally I just use jQuerys Waypoint Plugin. but it's not really the Angular Way. After Trying it from different angles, I came accross this npm package right here: [ngui/common](https://github.com/allenhwkim/ngui-common)

The **ngui-inview directive**  is exactly what I'm looking for but the  documentation sucks really bad. Its just showing how I can lazy load images... that's not what I want.

Does anyone here has some experience using this package? I really need some help here

Comment: I'd recommend using plain ol' built ins: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use intersection observer:

```
    // the element that you are observing (just add #yourElement in the template) for this  query to work
    @ViewChild('yourElement') yourElement: ElementRef;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        const threshold = 0.2; // how much % of the element is in view
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
            (entries) => {
                entries.forEach((entry) => {
                    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                        // run your animation code here
                        observer.disconnect(); // disconnect if you want to stop observing else it will rerun every time its back in view. Just make sure you disconnect in ngOnDestroy instead
                    }
                });
            },
            { threshold }
        );
        observer.observe(this.yourElement.nativeElement);
    }
```

There is no need for any additional packages/dependencies this feature is native to most modern browsers now.

See https://caniuse.com/intersectionobserver

More details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API